# update asp.net label located on a control in master page from the content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page in my asp.net application which has a user control named menu like this:

```
  <asp:Literal ID="SavedCVLiteral" runat="server" Text="1" /
```

and a public property like this:

```
 public string lbl_Text
        {
            get { return SavedCVLiteral.Text; }
            set { SavedCVLiteral.Text = value; }
        }
```

In my master page, I have created a property like this:

```
<%@ Register Src="Controls/CompanyLhsMenu.ascx" TagName="CompanyLhsMenu" TagPrefix="uc" %>


 <uc:CompanyLhsMenu ID="menu" runat="server" />


     public string SavedCVCount
            {
                get { return menu.lbl_Text; }
                set { menu.lbl_Text = value; }
            }
```

in my content page, I want to update the label so I added this:

```
 <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/LoggedCompany.master" %>
```

and using it like this:

```
 int count = HREmployee.GetSavedCVsCount(EmployeeID);
            Master.SavedCVCount = count.ToString();
```

but it is not updating the label and no error as well. I set break points and they are not hit in master page and control's properties.

Please suggest how to update label located on a control in master page from the content page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place following code into content page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl US = FindControl("CompanyLhsMenu") as UserControl;
    Literal ltrel;

    try
    {
        US = (UserControl)Master.FindControl("menu");

        ltrel = (Literal)US.FindControl("SavedCVLiteral");

        if (ltrel != null)
        {
            ltrel.Text = "update it";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Masterpage as a property on your current page. master page controls are protected so you can access them by using FindControl(string name). Try something like that

```
// Gets a reference to a Literal control inside a ContentPlaceHolder
ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
Literal ltrel;
mpContentPlaceHolder = 
    (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
if(mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
{
    ltrel = (Literal) mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("SavedCVLiteral");
    if(ltrel != null)
    {
        ltrel .Text = "update it";
    }
}
```

You have to this kind of scenario..

Hope it helps..